# imageview not showing, wieght and height 0

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview, android-image

Hello and thank you for taking the time to read this. I am a beginner in Android though I have experience in C# and C++. I am currently generating a qr with a button that is supposed to turn an invisible imageview visible. here is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ChargeActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/currency_amount"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="272dp"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:hint="Ingrese el monto"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/include"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="center" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="-143dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="-12dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/generateqr_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="Generar QR"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/include"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="center" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/transactions"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="19dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/qr_image"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and here is my java

```
public class ChargeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String ARG_USER = "USER";
    String user = "";
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private ImageView qrImage;
    private String inputValue;
    private EditText amount;
    private ListView transactions;

    private Spinner spinner;
    private static final String[] currencies = {"Bolivars", "Petros", "Dollars"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_charge);

        user = getIntent().getStringExtra(ARG_USER);



        qrImage = findViewById(R.id.qr_image);
        qrImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle(user);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // Get a support ActionBar corresponding to this toolbar
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_charge);
        //Spinner Setup
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ChargeActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, currencies);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        //ListView Setup
        transactions = findViewById(R.id.transactions);
        ArrayList<String> transaction_list = new ArrayList<String>();
        transaction_list.add("bolaeyunke te ha enviado 1920 petros");
        transaction_list.add("bolaeyunke te ha enviado 1932232320 bolivares");
        transaction_list.add("bolaeyunke te ha enviado 1923230 dolares");
        transaction_list.add("El Comandante te ha enviado 120 petros");
        ArrayAdapter transaction_adapter = new ArrayAdapter(ChargeActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, transaction_list);
        transactions.setAdapter(transaction_adapter);
        //Generate QR button setup
        Button generateQRButton = findViewById(R.id.generateqr_button);
        generateQRButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                amount = findViewById(R.id.currency_amount);
                String montos = amount.getText().toString();
                inputValue =  user + ";" + adapter.getItem(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()).toString()+";"+amount.getText().toString();
                //setting up for qr display
                WindowManager manager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
                Display display = manager.getDefaultDisplay();
                Point point = new Point();
                display.getSize(point);
                int width = point.x;
                int height = point.y;
                int smallerDimension = width < height ? width : height;
                smallerDimension = smallerDimension * 3 / 4;

                QRGEncoder qrgEncoder = new QRGEncoder(inputValue, null, QRGContents.Type.TEXT, smallerDimension);
                qrgEncoder.setColorBlack(Color.RED);
                qrgEncoder.setColorWhite(Color.BLUE);
                try {
                    // Getting QR-Code as Bitmap
                    bitmap = qrgEncoder.getBitmap();
                    // Setting Bitmap to ImageView


                    qrImage.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 120, 120, false));

                    qrImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    //Still need to implement an escape from showing the qr image

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.getMessage();
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

My imageview not only stays invisible, but when I debug, I see that the width and height are 0 for the imageview. I get no errors but it just does not show. I added the bitmap resizing after reading through some questions and thinking that that was the problem.

Comment: maybe you drop in catch block so the `e.getMessage();` is displayed

Comment: @Zain I am not sure I follow but I have placed a breakpoint in the catch block on the e.getmessage() line and I never hit it. Maybe I am being dumb.

Comment: if you temporarily force a static image to be displayed in `qr_image` via `android:src=`, does it display?  This will help identify if issue is with layout or code.

Comment: @CSmith it does i tried a white bg and it did work though it disregarded me making it invisible and would just show up constantly